# Terraform Variable Not Available

Tags: terraform

I am writing a terraform module to create a launch configuration along with ASG. It will create a "`aws_key_pair`" only if the keyname is not passed to the module for the ec2 instance. if the keyname is passed then use that keyname instead. I am doing it using the count function.

This all works fine. But when I pass the key to the module and try to use it in the launch configuration it is giving me the error that "`aws_key_pair.key_pair.id`" does not exist, which in a way is correct because  it was not created since I passed the key. But somehow terraform is trying to look for the "`aws_key_pair.key_pair.id`" variable which does not exist.

Seems like a terraform problem in variable handling. I had the same problem with subnet but I was able to use it by using the coalesce function but this does not seems to work in case of key:

```
key_name   = "${var.my_key == "" ?aws_key_pair.key_pair.id :var.my_key}"
```

This works for security groups:

```
  security_groups      = ["${coalesce(var.security_group,join("",aws_security_group.security_group.*.id))}"]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code you've provided isn't complete enough for someone to see what you're doing wrong here. You should edit your question to provide a [mcve], showing all the relevant code and showing file paths for things if it's not all in one file.

Comment: That `coalesce` trick is for variables with empty values, and not those with `null`/`undefined` values.

Comment: Terraform doesn't support the count parameter for modules currently: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/953